# Share text with picture to telegram

Tags: java, android, share, telegram

I want to create an app in Android and I want to share text with a picture to telegram but I do not want the pictures and the text to be separated. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it works fine, I tried same.

```
$.sendPhoto(image_url,{caption : 'i am attached text with image'});
//bot.sendPhoto(chatId,image_url,{caption : 'i am attached text with image'}); /* TRY these according to you.
```

Or, if you want to send it from Telegram rest api, then call this api:

```
API URL : 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendPhoto?
chat_id='+chatID+'&photo='+imageSrc+'&caption='+(message ?message : '');

METHOD : GET
```